# Retrieving documents in order they were inserted

Tags: rethinkdb

I am wanting to know how to create an index in rethinkdb that will return rows in the order they were added, to use it as a kind of log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set a `datetime` field of some sort in your documents like so:

```
# Shorthand for table
test = r.db("test").table("test")

# Create index
test.createIndex("datetime", r.row("datetime"))

# Insert document with datetime field
test.insert({
 datetime: r.now(),
})

# To get all documents in sorted order
test.order_by(index="datetime")

# To get documents after a certain point
test.between(<some sort of datetime object>, r.maxval, index="datetime")
```

- https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/order_by/
- https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/between/

Comment: I did think of this, however if I have 2+ webapp servers sending data, and their time is slightly out, then the log data may be inserted in a different order to the timestamp, so I can't really trust a timestamp.

Comment: `r.now` generates a timestamp once it's received _on the server_, so you should be fine there from client time inconsistencies. https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/now/

Comment: Looks good, thanks for that, if I cluster the database in the future, is the now() always calculated on the master? (No sharding, just replication)

Comment: On the primary node for that table, yes.